# love2D love.physics and setting images to body

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to set a image to a physics body in Love2D. I have got to the part where I have an image on a physical object, but I can't seem to only have the image and make the body of the physics object transparent.

I have a class so I can easily create instances of bodies. Here is the draw function:

```
function object:Draw()
    love.graphics.polygon("fill",self.body:getWorldPoints(self.shape:getPoints()))
    if self.image then
        love.graphics.draw(self.image, self.body:getX(), self.body:getY(), self.body:getAngle(),  1, 1, self.image:getWidth()/2, self.image:getHeight()/2)
    end
end
```

If I draw self.image before filling the polygon, it seems to not show anything at all.

Can anyone help me get the result I need?

All of object.lua:

```
local object = {}
local object_mt = { __index = object }
function object.newRect(world,x,y,width,height,typeOfBody,sprite)
  local instance = {}
  setmetatable(instance, object_mt)
  instance.body = love.physics.newBody(world, x, y, typeOfBody or nil)  -- create a body at x,y
  instance.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(x,y,width,height)
  instance.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(instance.body,instance.shape)  -- create a fixture of width/height
  instance.image = sprite and love.graphics.newImage(sprite) or nil
  return instance
end
function object:Draw()
    love.graphics.polygon("fill",self.body:getWorldPoints(self.shape:getPoints()))
    if self.image then
        love.graphics.draw(self.image, self.body:getX(), self.body:getY(), self.body:getAngle(),  1, 1, self.image:getWidth()/2, self.image:getHeight()/2)
    end
end
function object.getPosition()
  return self.body:GetPosition()
end
return object
```

Comment: you provide two different versions of object:Draw(). which one is the one you want to use? what do you mean with "it shows nothing at all?" not even the polygon?

Comment: I was doing alpha wrong (doing 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 255), it shows the polygon but not the image. The different version of object:Draw() was just the same except it was in the wrong order since I editted the first version in the post editor and then copied the rest of the code from notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should just need to remove,

```
love.graphics.polygon("fill",self.body:getWorldPoints(self.shape:getPoints()))
```

from your `Draw` function to not draw the physics object. However, this would cause any of your objects without an `image` to not display anything. If you only want to remove the polygon from objects with and `image` then you could use something like this:

```
function object:Draw()
  if self.image then
    love.graphics.draw(
      self.image, self.body:getX(), self.body:getY(), self.body:getAngle(),
      1, 1, self.image:getWidth() / 2, self.image:getHeight() / 2
    )
  else
    love.graphics.polygon("fill", self.body:getWorldPoints(self.shape:getPoints()))
  end
end
```